# What is the origin of Americana?

Tags: etymology, nouns

I have checked on the NOAD, but I didn't find the origin of *Americana*; it's reported that it means *things associated with the culture and history of America, especially the United States*, but not the origin of the word.

I have a hypothesis, but it doesn't explain why *Americana* is a plural noun. Does anybody know the origin of the word?

Comment: Americana is the feminine form of Americano. It sounds to be an Italian form of the word America which is a name for inhabitant or the native of the land.

In Italian the plural form is Americane.

In Spanish the plural form is Americanas.

Comment: In Italian, _americana_ is both adjective and noun; it is not the plural form, differently from _Americana_.

Comment: @Manoochehr: No, Americana is not the feminine form of Americano (in English). "Americana" does not refer to a female native of America in English.

Comment: I think it's more possibly from Spanish, which anyway is the same word and meaning than in Italian, meaning American.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: check out http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/americana

Comment: @Manoochehr: Yes, that's what I said "in English" (twice). The page you linked to gives your derivation for Italian and Spanish, but those are irrelevant for English. For the English meaning see FX_'s answer or http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Americana

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from *America* and the suffix *-ana*, of which the NOAD says:

> (forming plural nouns) denoting things
>   associated with a person, place, or
>   field of interest: Americana |
>   Victoriana.
>
> Origin: from the neuter plural of the Latin adjectival ending 
>   *-anus*

I don't have any examples in mind other than those above: *Americana* and *Victoriana*.

Comment: There are plenty of other examples, though they're mostly fairly obscure - fittingly, "arcana" (items of obscure knowledge), but also: "Africana"; "Arthuriana" (items related to King Arthur); "Australiana" - and that's just for the letter A :-)