The name Indiana
It was fairly easy to find that the place name "Indiana" means "land of the Indians" or "Indian Territory".  Please set side the whole debate over the origins of the word "Indian".  My question is basically why does adding an "a" to the end of a word, suddenly changes to "land of"? And from what language tradition does that come from?
I actually live in a town called Indiana that is located in the county of Indiana in the state of Pennsylvania.  Yes, it commonly confuses people.  But the short basic history is, as the settlers starting taking more and more land, pushing the Native population westward, the region beyond the land they had taken control of with some new treaty or another, was called Indiana Territory, or such. So, at one point, this region of PA was on the edge of one of the treaty boundaries, and then the next treaty brought it too the Colony/English control. So, some of the new land became Indiana County, and the town became Indiana.  Same basic principles happened in the naming of the state.  And again, that was a BASIC summarized history, that is missing a lot of detail.

I always assumed they probably started out with "Indiania" and thought it sounded too weird.

What research have you done? With only a brief bit of web searching, I came to the hypothesis - which I haven't looked to confirm - that it may have originated in Latin, when many of the provinces of the Roman Empire were given names matching the local ethnicity - Francia, Gallia, Germania, Dacia, etc.

I don't know for sure, but adding ia (from Latin) seems more frequent. So, Indiania.

I'm hearing a for related to in general and maybe plural: Judaica, apocrypha, ephemera.

See similar https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/what-is-the-origin-of-americana, in which adding "-a" to words already ending in "-an" means not "land of" but simply "having to do with." And I guess with @YosefBaskin 's comment above, it's not limited to "-an."

I think of it as an adjactive: terra Indiana.
